# How to change the label name in a root node and terminal node in a classification tree plot

Tags: r, rpart

In my data set, the outcome variable is a binary (No drop vs Drop, and No drop is the majority). I want to identify variables which are related to identify 'Drop out' using a classification tree. When I plotted my classification tree using the prp() function in R, the label of root node or terminal nodes always gave me 'No drop label'. I want to use 'drop out' instead.

I am using the R package `rpart` to produce a tree.

Comment: Why don't you just change your variable name from "No drop" to "Drop out" before doing rpart?

Comment: Thanks David, the outcome variable was named 'Drop out'. I try to change my code from (0 no drop; 1 drop) to (0 no drop; 1 drop). But it didn't work as well. Could you please give more suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  Did you try: `prp(..., left = F)`?

Comment: Hi David, it doesn't work as well. This argument (left=F) only changes the direction of (YES VS NO),  and cannot change the label. BTY, do you know how to output the delta (reduction in impurity) caused by each cut point of  a variable in rpart